# apply style to table except cells in current column

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to apply a style to all cells in the table, except cells in the current column.

I am trying to do something like this but it does not seem to work. What am I missing?

```
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    $("#myTable td:nth-child(:not(col-1))").addClass("myClass");

    <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="click">click</span></td>
        <td><span class="click">click</span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//bind click event handler to the `.click` elements
$('#myTable').find('.click').on('click', function () {

    //remove class from all TDs
    $('#myTable').find('td').removeClass('myClass');

    //get the index of the clicked element based on its parents siblings
    var index = $(this).closest('td').index();

    //iterate though each TD element in the table and add the class to it if it isn't the same index as the clicked element
    $.each($('#myTable').find('tr').children(), function () {
        if ($(this).index() != index) {
            $(this).addClass('myClass');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hU5qW/1/

This removes the custom class from all the TD elements, then add it to the ones not in the column with the SPAN clicked. Note that if you call `.index()` on an element, you will get the index of that element based on its sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since `col` is a variable, you have to use string concatenation. You also need to put `:not` before.

```
var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this))-1;
$("#myTable td:not(:nth-child("+col+"))").addClass("myClass");
```